# sign out and redirect to separate sign-out page on asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hell, I am working on sign-out feature and try to update the redirection. Right now when sign-out is clicked. In my signout action of home controller `return RedirectToAction("SignOut", "Authenticate")` will successfully sign out and  display user the standard signout page.

```
RedirectResult SignOut()
{
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  Session.Abadon();
  Redirect(SignOutEndPoint);
}
```

I am try to get user to the sign-in page instead of the standard sign-out page. I am stilled signed in after the following code. By calling this code, it return 500. Could some pointing me out the right way to do this ? Thanks.

```
ActionResult temp = RedirectToAction("SignOut", "Authenticate");
return View("~")
```

A different way to ask, is there a way to intercept the `return RedirectToAction("SignOut", "Authenticate")` and process additional redirect on it?

Comment: Redirect the user to the sign in action method after calling the 2 methods to clear session and form auth cookies

Comment: @Shyju, there other operation in the SignOutEndPoint that I cannot control, so I have to redirect to it, and then get user to the log in? can I redirect twice in one action ?